# AWS Cloudwatch event rule schedule UTC time example

Tags: cron, amazon-cloudwatch, cron-task

I've configured CloudWatch events to run every 1AM Myanmar time and 8AM Myanmar time as follows:

run 1am Myanmar Time
`30 18 * * ? *`
[image]

run 8am Myanmar Time
`30 1 * * ? *`
[image]

Unfortunately, CloudWatch is not running on those certain times ? Please let me know if my UTC configuration time is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scheduled expression is correct, but I can see the status as **Disabled**,
Please **Enable** and try.

On CloudWatch screen: See right top for Actions drop down,

Actions > click 'Enable'

Comment: that's my careless mistake.